# How to dynamic add users to AccessPackages in AzureAD under entitlement management?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

You've got this great new feature in Azure AD under Entitlement management: Access Packages.
Packages including groups and what more for specific users and roles.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/entitlement-management-access-package-create

The issue I'm struggling with, is how can I add users by dynamic group without them having to request access first?

I feel like I'm overseeing something, but as it looks now you can only add a Dynamic Group & the users in the group can request access to the AccessPackages.

Has anyone else dealt with this already?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the references and if below can be worked around in your case.

According to [Create a new access package in entitlement management - Azure AD | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/entitlement-management-access-package-create#none-administrator-direct-assignments-only).

If you want to bypass access requests and allow administrators to **directly assign specific users** to this access package.  click **None (administrator direct assignments only)** in request section to create a policy where users need not request for access. For this group selection is not there.Users won't have to request the access package.

But if you need to select specific dynamic group for policy .

1. You can create a access package with dynamic groups selected  .

[image]

2. You can create a policy separately for the users for dynamic group with require approval disabled and requests disabled.

[image]

3. Then while assignment requests are bypassed and approved even if the policy has request approval.
   Even if require approval and requests are enabled in first step, you can set a separate policy by setting the by pass approval to yes.

[image]

> *Note* :**Dynamic group** is to be given the **owner role** for access packages.

[image]

Reference: [active-directory-entitlement-management-request-policy | (github)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/includes/active-directory-entitlement-management-request-policy.md)

Comment: Hi, I think that you misunderstand me. I want the Dynamic Security Group members automatically be assigned to the Access Packages by GroupMembership. I followed your stepts but unfortunately it's not working right now. No member in the Group is auto assigned the Accesspackage. Or is that not what you meant?